# Restrict Pull Requests Between specific Branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have a pre-deployment branch and a production branch, and would like to set security such that you can only create pull requests to the production from pre deployment and not from other branches.

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are workaround to achieve this.

You should first create a build pipeline with a powershell task executing below script to check if the pull request source branch is the restricted branch.

```
$sourceBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

if($sourceBranch -ne "refs/heads/pre-deployment")
{
    exit 1
}
```

And then add this build pipeline to the **build policy** under **Build validation** in **branch policies** of your production branch. After setting above build policy, the new pull request will trigger the build pipeline and fail if the source branch is not pre-deployment

[image]

Another way to do this is creating a pull request status server. please refer to the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=azure-devops) for more information